# convert simple for loop on arrow function es6

Tags: javascript

Hey I have one question simple for loop and arrow functions in es6. I have simple for loop I try make the same effect using arrow functions. Please look on code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < app.productsPag.length; i++){
    if(app.productsPag[i]._id == data.id){
        app.productsPag[i].description = data.description
   }
}
```

Code above works very good.
And ES6:

```
app.productsPag.forEach(item => item._id == data.id).filter(arr => arr.description == data.description)
```

But his not working.

Comment: The `==` is a [comparison operator](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp). But the `=` is an [assignment operator](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_assignment.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `.filter`, you should use it *before* the `forEach` so that you iterate over the filtered array while assigning to the `description` property:

```
app.productsPag.filter(({ _id }) => _id === data.id)
  .forEach(product => product.description = data.description);
```

As comment says, iterating over the objects twice like this is pretty silly - while this looks to be closest to what your original code was trying to achieve, you'd be better using only a single `forEach` with a test inside:

```
app.productsPag.forEach((product) => {
  if (product._id === data.id) product.description = data.description;
});
```

But it sounds like there might only be one matching product. If this is the case, you should use `find` instead of `filter`:

```
const foundProduct = app.productsPag.find(({ _id }) => _id === data.id);
if (foundProduct) foundProduct.description = data.description;
```

in ES5 syntax, the destructuring in the function parameters is equivalent to the following:

```
var foundProduct = app.productsPag.find(function(product) {
  return product._id === data.id;
});
if (foundProduct) foundProduct.description = data.description;
```

Better to use only a single `forEach` with a test inside if multiple objects can match

Comment: really filter with foreach o_O?

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty silly, but looks like the closest to what OP's original code was trying for initially

Answer (score 4):

Just find and update with a default object.

```
var object = (app.productsPag.find(({ _id }) => _id ===data.id) || {})
        .description = data.description;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to manipulate / change existing data, creating another variable would not make any sense.

*Btw === also checks the type and is usually preferred over ==*

One line:

```
app.productsPag.find(obj => obj.id === data.id)['description'] = data.description;
```